# how can i get meld woking with git extensions on windows?

Tags: windows, git, git-extensions, meld

I've already set up meld on git extensions like this - 
[meld config in git extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eg7y.png).

But when I try to see the file diff, I get this error - 
[error of git extensions diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOLaM.png).

So I install gtk+ following steps on https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php. 
When all done, I tried diff again but same error shows up
[error of git extensions diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOLaM.png).

I searched everything online, but can not fix this problem. It's let me crazy, plz help me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: im usin git extensions 3.0.2  git version 2.20.1.windows.1 and meld 3.20,just open meld.exe is ok,but with git extensions has problem

Comment: Hi @withe john, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to edit your question and add the appropriate capital letters and punctuation. You might also want to have a look at the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: my english is so bad,im sorry,thk u for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem: git extensions version 3.0.2 cannot use meld version 3.20, so I reinstalled meld version 3.18 and now it works!